# How to show data between two date range in spline chart of Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highchart to show the data on spline chart. Here I have two date range from 2021-09-12T18:30:00.000Z to 2021-09-18T18:29:59.999Z which will change according to date range selection.

**Issue:** The spline chart x-axis range tick starts with the date 11 and my graph starts from second tick that is 12. I want the x-axis tick should start from 12 and end with 18 like the above date range and the data given below. I am adding JS fiddle link for the reference.[Spline Chart](https://jsfiddle.net/45eofq13/1/) Thank you.

```
[
  {
    name: 'Allowed Request',
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,12), 2202],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,13), 1234],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,14), 1245],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,15), 3000],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,16), 2345],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,17), 2505],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,18), 4933],
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Denied Request',
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,12), 1234],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,13), 2202],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,14), 3000],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,15), 3000],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,16), 2345],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,17), 3000],
      [Date.UTC(2021,8,18), 2505],
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config, there is a `startOnTick` option which is set as true. Change it to false solve the issue.

However, if you want to keep this space which is added by `startOnTick` option, you can leave it as a true, but you need to add `showFirstLabel` property set a false.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qnfe7w05/